# Is there a reason for the backticks and echo in "export var=`echo ${var1}/...`"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This query is with regards to how environment variables in Linux are declared in a environment setup file viz environment_var.sh. This file has a bunch of export commands (something like below ) -

```
echo "Input Variable: "$1
if [ $1 = "value1" ]; then
variable1=""
else
variable1=$1
fi  

export variable2=app_name${variable1}.subcategory2
export variable3=`echo ${variable1}/subfolder1/`
```

My query is related to the second export statement where echo has been used for variable 3. Is there any specific reason for using echo or could it have been declared as below without the need to use backtick and echo -

```
export variable3=${variable1}/subfolder1/
```

Appreciate your inputs in this regard.

Comment: Yep. The `echo` is useless.

Comment: The only thing I would change there is to put double quotes around it in  case there is embedded whitespace in the directory names:  `export variable3="${variable1}/subfolder1/"`.  I can't see any reason for the `echo` or the out-dated back-ticks.   I would also quote all the instances of `"$1"` for the same reason.

Comment: The only reason an `echo` is useful in situations like this is if you want to use some other command to modify the variable. For example var3=`echo ${var1} | sed 's/from/to/'`. But as others have said, it is extraneous in the sample you posted.

Comment: @Turn:  surely no one uses `sed` like that any more?  `var3=${var1/from/to}`

Comment: @cdarke True, but it was just an example, you could use any command to transform the variable.

Comment: @Turn, ...but if you *were* going to do that, it'd still be better to avoid `echo`, which has undefined behavior if `var1='-n'` or contains backslashes. And without quotes (which you didn't have in your example), `var1='*'` would cause `echo $var1` to emit a list of filenames. See also the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: @Turn, ...while I'm on the topic: `echo ${var1}` has no correctness advantage whatsoever over `echo $var1`, whereas `echo "$var1"` at least prevents string-splitting and glob expansion; even then, if you want to be sure content is emitted unmunged, `printf '%s\n' "$var1"` is preferable to any of the formulations mentioned prior.

Answer (score 3):

The `echo` is **worse than useless**.  With `echo`, your directory name is subject to both *pathname expansion* and *word splitting*.

For example, consider a directory with these subdirectories:

```
$ find . -name 'subfolder1'
./dir1/subfolder1
./dir*/subfolder1
./dir2/subfolder1
```

Now, let's execute the command with `echo`:

```
$ var1='dir*'
$ var3=`echo ${var1}/subfolder1/`
```

To display the precise value of `var3`, let's use `declare -p`:

```
$ declare -p var3
declare -- var3="dir1/subfolder1/ dir2/subfolder1/ dir*/subfolder1/"
```

Because of *pathname expansion*, `var3` is changed from what one might expect.

Now, let's try again without `echo`:

```
$ var1='dir*'
$ var3=${var1}/subfolder1/
$ declare -p var3
declare -- var3="dir*/subfolder1/"
```

In this case, no *pathname expansion* was performed and `var3` is exactly what we assigned it to be.

**Conclusion: don't use the `echo` form unless you explicitly want *pathname expansion* or *word splitting*.**

As [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) points out, if you did want *pathname expansion*, then you probably also want to use arrays, not `echo`.  Observe:

```
$ var1='dir*'
$ arr3=(${var1}/subfolder1/)
$ declare -p arr3
declare -a arr3=([0]="dir1/subfolder1/" [1]="dir2/subfolder1/" [2]="dir*/subfolder1/")
```

Here, all three directory names appear correctly as separate entries in `arr3`.

#### Still more problems with echo

Using bash, observe:

```
$ var1='-n dir'
$ var3=`echo ${var1}/subfolder1/`
$ declare -p var3
declare -- var3="dir/subfolder1/"
```

In this case, we assigned `var1` to `-n dir` but, in `var3`, the `-n` disappeared.  That is because it was interpreted not as an argument to be printed but as an option to `echo` and `echo` gobbled it up.

Comment: Even if one *does* want glob expansion, there are better ways to get it; `directory_array=( ./dir*/subdir1 ); IFS=':'; colon_separated_directory_list="${directory_array[*]}"` is considerably better-defined in terms of how it'll behave in the corner cases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, exactly right.  And, your point about `-n` is also a good one.

Comment: Hello @John1024, can you please explain how you got $ declare -p var3
declare -- var3="dir1/subfolder1/ dir2/subfolder1/ dir*/subfolder1/". When I execute the same in my terminal, I still get the results which same as your second example i.e. declare without the backtick and echo declare -- var3="dir*/subfolder1/"
Apologies if I am missing something here.

Comment: @KanetkarRev Does `dir1/subfolder1/` or  `dir2/subfolder1/` exist in your directory?  If they don't exist, then pathname expansion won't find them.

Comment: Thank you @John1024. The pathname expansion works after adding the directories.